# Hotspot dropping

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Ok guys, I serched all the internet for a solution and couldn`t find...

I found a couple of topics about hotspot problems here and there but none of them were exactly my problem or would fix my problem...

I have a Moto X Play, and when I create an wi-fi hotspot to use the internet on my laptop, every few seconds, sometimes minutes, the hotspot signal is gone, and than it comes back by itself...  after a while it doesn`t come back at all and I have to reset my phone,

When I enter my hotspot configs there's no such thing as "timeout option", as there are in other Androids,

I saw a guy saying that he fixed his problem by removing the screen block pattern and changing the sleep time to 15s. For me it doesn`t work..

What it looks like is that when my 4g signal is a bit low, the hotspot turns off and on again, maybe to try to get a better signal, but I don`t know.

Somewhere I found people saying that it was some config about battery-saving. I tried to change some of those configs on my battery options, as to change Android System for example from 'saving battery' to 'not save battery' but it also didn`t work..

If anyone has a tip or know how to fix it please let me know, Im desperate already. My laptop has few USB sockets and it`d be good if I didn't have to use 1 for USB-tethering.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

Scan and clean your mobile using Cache cleaner or Internet booster application may solve your issue